# Error al correr Update-Database | Asp.NET | A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server

Tags: sql, asp.net

Estoy configurando la base de mi aplicación en Asp.NET y al ejecutar Update-Database en Package Manager Console me arroja el siguiente error:

> A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance Specified)

Mi código es el siguiente:

Startup.cs

```
public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        Configuration = configuration;
    }

    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddMvc();
        services.AddDbContext<PaymentDetailContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DevConnection")));
    }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }

        app.UseMvc();
    }
```

appsettings.json

```
{
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "DevConnection": "Server=(local)\\sqlexpress;Database=PaymentDetailDB;Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True"
  },
  "Logging": {
    "IncludeScopes": false,
    "Debug": {
      "LogLevel": {
        "Default": "Warning"
      }
    },
    "Console": {
      "LogLevel": {
        "Default": "Warning"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Realmente no comprendo muy bien lo que estoy haciendo ya que lo hago siguiendo un tutorial, pero entiendo que el comando crea la base con las entidades que creé como tablas.

¿Qué estoy haciendo mal?

Comment: ¿Has visto si el servicio del SQL server está funcionando?

Comment: @fredyfx cómo puedo verlo? En este tutorial que estoy siguiendo no menciona antes nada de SQL server.

Comment: inicio, ejecutar, `services.msc` Por cierto, cambia el orden de lo que tienes en `ConfigureServices` primero va el contexto, luego el MVC. La cadena de conexión está mal hecha, verifica si ese es el nombre de la instancia de la base de datos sea esa misma

Comment: @fredyfx lo único de SQL que veo corriendo es SQL Server VSS Writer.

Comment: @fredyfx lo del nombre de la instancia no sé cómo hacerlo...

Comment: ¿Has instalado el sql server express?

Comment: @fredyfx sí, de hecho lo uso diariamente

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/94514/discussion-between-fredyfx-and-facundo-yuffrida).